# How to set index of ajax appended nested fields_for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, fields-for

Hi I have a `character` form with fields_for `skill_of_objects` nested attribute.

Some skills are generate based on the fixed number of `skills_of_objects` that need to be added to the character. And loop like this generates input name and id values correctly.

```
<input value="224" type="hidden" name="character[skill_of_objects_attributes][0][skill_id]" id="character_skill_of_objects_attributes_0_skill_id" />
<input value="23" type="hidden" name="character[skill_of_objects_attributes][1][skill_id]" id="character_skill_of_objects_attributes_1_skill_id" />
<input value="248" type="hidden" name="character[skill_of_objects_attributes][2][skill_id]" id="character_skill_of_objects_attributes_2_skill_id" />
```

and so on... as long as this is done in the main iteration, it gives proper index number.

But when I make ajax append fields_form, I'm creating new `f` builder:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @character] do |f| %>
  $('#skill_list').append("<%= j render partial: 'add_skill', locals: { character: @character, skill: @skill, f: f } %> ");
<% end %>
```

And along with this I loose proper index value, and appended partial generates input with 0 index:

```
<input value="244" type="hidden" name="character[skill_of_objects_attributes][0][skill_id]" id="character_skill_of_objects_attributes_0_skill_id" />
```

**Problem:**

How to set corrct value of this input field.

Comment: The form does not do a loop so it's only sending one value through the partial. Are you using a loop for the form? That could be the answer.

Comment: I use partial only for appended forms, because I need, display static forms different.

Answer (score 0):

I ended in striping index value in my coffeescript action:

```
name = $('#skill_list li.skill:last input').attr('name')
  index = name.replace /[^0-9]/g, ''
```

I pass it as parameter, incremented it, and generate proper `id`, and `name` in my append partial.

```
%li.skill{ id: "skill_#{skill.name_pl.squish.tr(' ','_')}"}
  = f.fields_for :skill_of_objects, character.skill_of_objects.build do |ff|
    %strong
      = skill.name_pl
    = ff.hidden_field :skill_id, value: skill.id, name: "character[skill_of_objects_attributes][#{index}][skill_id]", id: "character_skill_of_objects_attributes_#{index}_skill_id"
```